# How can I set face for echo-area message

Tags: faces, echo-area

When I print messages using `(message (propertize "text" 'face 'some-face))` properties get printed as text:

```
#("text" 0 4 (face some-face))
```

How can I have faces displayed properly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No they don't get printed as text. :-)

Evaluate the following function, then call `M-x mes`. Doesn't it work?

```
(defun mes ()
  "message me"
  (interactive)
  (message (propertize "text" 'face 'font-lock-warning-face)))
```

---

The problem, I imagine, is that you're evaluating your snippet with
something like `eval-last-sexp` (`C-x C-e`). This function (and its
brethren) prints the form's return value on the echo area, which is
what you're seeing (the `message` function also returns the string it
prints).

Your test code is working, but the message in the mode-line is getting
immediately replaced by the return value. That's why you can't see it.