# Define colors for single use in minibuffer

Tags: minibuffer, colors

I couldn't find anything on this, so I'm asking it here. I can display a message in minibuffer with

```
(message "foo bar")
```

I would like to give only the message "foo bar" a red color in the minibuffer. Is that possible with Emacs?

Comment: If you use `M-x customiz-group RET minibuffer RET` you can customize various aspects of how things appear in the `minibuffer`. Not sure if it is what you want, but it would be a good place to start. I am not entirely sure if you want to do this as part of some commands that you are writing, or just a general way to customize the face of the text in the minibuffer.

Comment: No, I want to keep the default colorscheme of minibuffer, but for only specific messages I want to colorize them differently from the rest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a string with faces.

```el
(message (propertize "foo bar" 'face 'highlight))
```

Or use a different face, which has a red foreground.  Or use a face property list:

```el
(message (propertize "foo bar" 'face '(:foreground "Red")))
```

Comment: When I tried this it showed `#("foo bar" 0 7 (face highlight))` in the echo area, but this answer explained why - you can't use C-x C-e to test it out... http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2331/how-can-i-set-face-for-echo-area-message

Comment: Thanks Drew! I was already looking why it didn't worked properly, until I noticed @bburns.km message.Thanks for sharing that link!

Comment: Use `(defun foo () (interactive) (message...))` with `M-x foo`, to test.